# Calculate difference between dates in months and based on defined deadline MS EXCEL

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

everyone. I am trying to get the difference between two dates in Excel based on a defined deadline which is the 10th the following month. Please see sample below.

```
Month    | Deadline      | Date Paid     | Month/s Elapsed | Remarks
Jan 2020 | Feb. 10, 2020 | Feb. 10, 2020 | 1               | One 10th has passed
Jan 2020 | Feb. 10, 2020 | Mar. 13, 2020 | 2               | Two 10th have passed based on Date Paid
Mar 2020 | Apr. 10, 2020 | Jun. 27, 2020 | 3               | Three 10th have passed from Mar 2020 - June 27, 2020
```

Basically, should the Date Paid fall beyond the 10th of the following month, it should count how many 10ths have elapsed from the deadline to the date paid. Here is my formula so far and it's not taking into account the deadline which is the 10th every month.

```
=MONTH(c2)-MONTH(B2)
```

Could you kindly provide any ideas as to how I can achieve the expected output?

I hope my question is clear. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You can't just work with the months. You have to subtract dates, because you may span years. So you could have 12+ months difference. Or span a year.. Dec to Jan in your scenario.

Comment: In your current sampledata you could use `=DATEDIF(B2,C2,"M")+1`

Answer (score 2):

[image]

In your current setup it looks like you could just use:

```
=DATEDIF(B2,C2,"M")+1
```

Not sure if that would be error-proof for all your cases. The following should return the amount of dates in an array that are equal to the 10th of that month:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(DAY(ROW(INDEX(A:A,A2):INDEX(A:A,C2))=10))
```

This is with the assumption that column A holds dates that are the last days of those months!

Comment: @Isabella, glad it helped. Don't forget to check the question as answered =)